# Not really getting the useReducer hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-reducer

I'm trying to change a value from a select menu. My code is working, but I think this would go better if I used useReducer.Am I correct? I tried to change it, but I just can't seem to make it work... At the documentation it says that:

> "useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
> state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
> depends on the previous one."

I think I should be using it right?

```
 const [diametro, setDiametro] = useState(0);
 const [total, setTotal] = useState("0");
 useEffect(
     () => setTotal(() => ((preco / 100) * diametro).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")), [diametro]
      );
```

Comment: I think even `useEffect` could be overkill already. Why not call `setTotal` directly wherever you are currently updating `diametro` and `preco`? Keep in mind that code should be easy to read and maintain and the incurred asynchronicity of `useEffect` might already be confusing – let alone `useReducer`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) is the correct hook to use in your case. Basically, you are 'deriving' the value of `total` from the current value of `diametro`. This means that the value of `total` only changes if the value of `diametro` changes.

The code would then look something like this:

```
const [diametro, setDiametro] = useState(0);
const total = useMemo(() =>
  ((preco / 100) * diametro).toFixed(2).replace(".", ","),
  [diametro]
);
```

In general, a guiding principle is to keep the actual state to the bare minimum, and then use hooks like `useMemo` to derive the other properties you need. Remember that is is also okay to return multiple properties as an object from `useMemo`, so you can derive multiple values with only one `useMemo` call.

Comment: Thanks man. Worked it just great! Just to clarify one think, the application is changing correctly but I placed a console.log at the useMemo function and this console is one state behind, why is that?

Comment: Good to hear! The console.log problem can depend on where and how you log the values. The `setDiametro` function does not immediately change the value of `diametro`. This is an important reason to have correct dependency arrays as last parameter to hooks.

Comment: So, to make sure you are logging the latest value of `total`, you need to use useEffect:
`useEffect(() => console.log({ total }), [total])`
In this way React will make sure to call console.log at the right point in time when `diametro` and `total` are in sync. If you don't use `useEffect`, or supply a different dependency array, unexpected things may happen. This is inherent to the way hooks work in React I'm afraid.